# How to compare against each string in an array

Tags: ruby

I have an array that consists of sentences:

```
arr = ["Independence day - 04 July",
       "Valentine's day - 14 February",
       "Christmas - 25 December"]
```

If `arr` includes `"04 July"`, I want to print like `"on 04 July is Independence day"`.

Comment: Why do you store the data in such an unstructured way?

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.map { |str| str.gsub(/(.+) - (.+)/, '\2 is \1') }
  #=> ["04 July is Independence day",
  #    "14 February is Valentine's day",
  #    "25 December is Christmas"]
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters in capture group 1, followed by the string `' - '`, followed by one or more characters in capture group 2". `'\2 is \1'` forms the string comprised of the contents of capture group 2 followed by the string `' is '` followed by the contents of capture group 1.

If no spaces or extra spaces may surround the hyphen, change the regex to

```
/(.+) *- *(.+)/
```

Comment: My answer depends on an interpretation of the question that differs from the way that some others who have given answers understood what was being asked.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you need something like this:

```
if value is '04 July' #=> On 04 July is Independence Day
if value is '14 February' #=> On 14 February is Valentin's day
if value is '25 December' #=> On 25 December is Christmas
```

Try this

```
arr = ["Independence day - 04 July",
   "Valentin's day - 14 February",
   "Christmas - 25 December"]

value = '04 July'
arr.each do |element|
  festival, date = element.split('-').map(&:strip)
  if date.eql?(value)
    puts "On #{date} is #{festival}"
  end
end
```

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.each{|a| puts a if a.include? '04 July'}
```

Comment: These two are not equivalent. Don't suggest wrong ideas (that it's ok to use `map` for simple iteration)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Baurzhan Kozhaev wants to print "Independence day - 04 July". map and each makes this process. I edited my answer with the output. Please look.

Comment: He actually wants to print something else. Also the fact that something does produce the same side-effects doesn't mean it can/should be used for this. Using `map` for iteration is a WTF-moment. You could use `select`/`grep` for filtering and then `map` for transforming selected strings into desired format. That _would_ be idiomatic use of `map`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev okay, I understood now. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
puts 'on 04 July is Independence day' if arr.join(',').include?('04 July')
```

Or

```
string = '04 July'
arr.map{ |item| puts "on #{string} is a #{item.sub(" - #{string}", '')}" if item.include?string }
```

Or in another way

```
string = '04 July'
items = arr.select{|item| item.include?(string)} 
puts "on #{string} is a #{items.first.sub(" - #{string}", '')}" unless items.empty?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why `Enumerable#grep` exists

```
arr = ["Independence day - 04 July",
       "Valentin's day - 14 February",
       "Christmas - 25 December"]

str = "04 July"

arr.grep(Regexp.new(str)) # => ["Independence day - 04 July"]
```

This finds you the matching lines. Then you simply rearrange their parts for presentation. Although if you have to do this, why not store parts separately from the start? In an array of two elements or a hash, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
compare_value = '04 July'
arr.each do |str_val|
  puts str_val if str_val.include?(compare_value)
end
```

Comment: I just love a downvote without any comment, can't get enough of them :D